# C# How to create a generic list of students and grades and access those

Tags: c#, generics

I'm struggling with C# on something that should be really easy.  I need a temporary storage system for an unknown number of students and an unknown number of attributes about each student.

I'm basically getting an unknown number of students, then doing a query on each student to return their grades and other info which are probably different than any other student.

- Student 1: 
  Name: John 
  Last Name: Doe 
  Math 1010: A 
  Math 2020: B 
  Math 3010: B+ 
  Eng 1010: A-
- Student 2:
  Name: April
  Last Name: Johnson
  Geology 1000: C
  Math 1010: B
  etc...

Then at the end, I just need to step through each student and output their info.

I found this example which is good for one set of known items per student, but I think I need a list for each student, and I'm not sure how to make the "master" list. I could figure it out for arrays, but working generics is new to me.

```
List<Student> lstStudents = new List<Student>();

Student objStudent = new Student();
objStudent.Name = "Rajat";
objStudent.RollNo = 1;

lstStudents.Add(objStudent);

objStudent = new Student();
objStudent.Name = "Sam";
objStudent.RollNo = 2;

lstStudents.Add(objStudent);

//Looping through the list of students
foreach (Student currentSt in lstStudents)
{
    //no need to type cast since compiler already knows that everything inside 
    //this list is a Student
    Console.WriteLine("Roll # " + currentSt.RollNo + " " + currentSt.Name);
}
```

Comment: Good. And what is your question exactly?

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous - do you save the attributes in the `Student` class (in which case each student would have a `List` or a `Dictionary`) or do you want some sort of `Dictionary` to map `Student` objects to Attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a student class like:

```
    public class Student
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _customProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public Dictionary<string, object> CustomProperties { get { return _customProperties; } }
    }
```

And then use it like:

```
        List<Student> lstStudents = new List<Student>();

        Student objStudent = new Student();
        objStudent.CustomProperties.Add("Name", "Rajat");
        objStudent.CustomProperties.Add("RollNo", 1);

        lstStudents.Add(objStudent);

        objStudent = new Student();
        objStudent.CustomProperties.Add("Name", "Sam");
        objStudent.CustomProperties.Add("RollNo", 2);

        lstStudents.Add(objStudent);

        foreach (Student currentSt in lstStudents)
        {
            foreach (var prop in currentSt.CustomProperties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Key+" " + prop.Value);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your students need a field

```
class Student
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

With that you can store your unknown number of attributes.

Then looping

```
foreach(var student in studentsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("attr: " + student.Attributes["attr"]);
}
```

Of course you can mix with fixed properties too.
For good coding you should implement with properties and helper member functions. My example is very basic.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a `foreach` instead of `for`?

Comment: you are right. thanks. i mixed up some objc js syntax.